# How to select section of a sector as a region of interest in OpenCV using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, maze, roi

I want to extract a single cell of this maze as a region of interest. Assuming that each level of the maze has equal width how can I do so?
My approach was to calculate the value of four corner points of the cell and draw a custom mask using the inner and outer radius but I am unable to find a method to do so.

[image]

Comment: You can try working in the [polar coordinates](http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaa38a6884ac8b6e0b9bed47939b5362f3)

Comment: I tried to convert the entire image to polar form but it completely changed the image configuration.

Comment: Yeah... that's the idea ;D But now you can work on rectangles instead of circular sectors.

Comment: I tried to do that but the rectangles in the resulting image weren't distinct enough to work upon. @Miki could you please help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/40952304/7237528

Comment: (Luckily) I'll be off my pc for the weekend.. I'll check that on Monday.. good luck!